# The current version does not meet the minimum version requirements - Huawei Account Kit integration [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, huawei-mobile-services, pubspec, huawei-account

I am trying to integrate Huawei Account Kit in my flutter project. Since I am not using Huawei phone, I have downloaded the HMS Core in my phone which is version 3.0.0.300. The current version for Huawei Account Kit in my pubspec.yaml is 5.2.0+301.

I have already change the minSdkVersion to 19 before that. When I run my app, it says that I have not met the minimum version requirement. Any suggestions on solving this issue?

Below are my pubspec.yaml and some screenshot of the error messages.

```
name: account_kit
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  huawei_account: ^5.2.0+301

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/as-integration-hms-core-sdk-0000001050436235#section888494613128), try to configure Metadata:

```
<application ...>
    <meta-data     
        android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.channel.androidMarket"  
        android:value="false" />
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove version like this:

```
huawei_account:
```